# How to select rectangular text area in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, selection

I want to select a rectangular text area in my Word document, using keyboard shortcuts or the mouse. How can I do that?

```
 ------------
|aaaaaaaaaaaa| ,aaaaa, aaaaa
|bbbbbbbbbbbb| ,bbbbb, bbbbb
|cccccccccccc| ,ccccc, ccccc
|dddddddddddd| ,ddddd, ddddd
 ------------
```

Comment: Alt + mouse selects vertical block like shown.

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes !! This was the answer I look for

Answer (score 1):

Provided the text is stored in a file `test.txt`

In a cmd window use

```
for /F "delims=|" %A in ('findstr "|" test.txt') Do @echo %A
```

In a batch file:

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SU_1398481.cmd
@Echo off
for /F "delims=|" %%A in ('findstr "|" test.txt') Do @echo %%A
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\01\25\SU_1398481.cmd
aaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbb
cccccccccccc
dddddddddddd
```

- the `for /f` command parses the output of findstr, which only selects lines containing the vertical bar `|`
- `"delims=|"` in combination with the default `"tokens=1"` assign the for variable `%%A` the content between the vertical bars which the echo outputs.

---

In a program like Notepad++ you could use a RegEx to select the Text between the `|`

```
Search : (?m)^.*?(?<=\|)([^\|]+?)(?=\|).*$
Replace: $1
```

You'd need another one to remove the lines without vertical bars.